# app.get method in express package

Tags: node.js, express

when I run this code, runs without any problems.

```
httpApp.get("/friends", function(req, res) { res.redirect("/"); });
```

but i want do this for friends.html file. but not worked.

```
httpApp.get("/friends.html", function(req, res) { res.redirect("/"); });
```

Comment: No reason why `app.get("/friends.html", function(req, res) { res.redirect("/"); });` would not work. You can use any style to name your routes, node/express does not force you to follow anything. Can you share contents of `app.js`?

Comment: I'm working on easyRTC.
I want the app not to display some paths for users who are not yet members. I wanted to use it.
Is there any other way?

Comment: My app.js file has 200 lines. I'm sure other codes have no problem.

Comment: Ok. I would check routes to see if there's any rule that matches `/friends.html` and hence not working as expected. Do you get `Cannot GET /friends.html` or anything else?

Comment: i created /freindes.html. but i want this file only to users who are logged in can display. my orginal code: `httpApp.get('/friends.html', function(req, res) { if(!req.session.user) { res.redirect('/'); } });`

Comment: There's a file named `friends.html` in public. And you have static router before app.router in app.js. This explains it, the request for /friends.html never reaches your node code, as it has already been matched. If you place app.router before static, your route will match before the name based match. But this will also mean, every request for static assets will first go through all your routes, before being served from file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to serve up straight .html files, use `express.static`, explained over at http://expressjs.com/api.html#directory

If you don't, there is no reason to insist the URL is "friends.html", just keep it "friends". Or, if you really *really* need "friends.html" in the URL without it being a static html file, use a named variable in the route, add it to res.locals, and then process the request based on the page name:

```
app.get(...)
app.get(...)
app.post(...)
...etc...

// specific files on / last:
app.param("file", function(req,res,next,varcontent) {
  res.locals.filename = varcontent;
  next();
});

app.get("/:file", function(req, res, next) {
  ... user res.locals.filename here ...
});
```

Comment: thanks, I'm working on easyRTC. I want the app not to display some paths for users who are not yet members. I wanted to use it. Is there any other way?